# 403 Forbidden when making a multipart/form-data REST PUT API Call to Azure DataStore

Tags: apex, rest-api, callout, azure

As the title suggests, whenever I try to send an API request with a **PUT** method and a **multipart/form-data** as the content-type, to an Azure Data Store, I get a **403 Forbidden** response back.

I am using a named credential (with valid Auth Providers for authentication), and get the endpoint directly from it. The data is in JSON format, and I am not sending it as an application/json because the contents are too big; it was suggested that I submit it as a json within a multipart, so Azure identifies it as a file and applies different request size limits.

With the exact **same credentials**, I am able to use Postman. But on Salesforce, it fails. The contents of the **body** are exactly the **same** on both cases. The **headers** are **similar**, but the *important ones* are the same, e.g.: **content-length**, **x-ms-version**, **x-ms-blobtype** and **content-type**.

Here's some sample Apex code, on the Salesforce-side, that I use to make the request.

```java
String fileName = 'a_file.json';
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('callout:MyNamedCredential'+ '/path/' + fileName);
request.setMethod('PUT');
String boundaryString = 'aBoundaryString';
String fileHeader = 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"' + '; filename="' + fileName + '"' + '\nContent-Type: application/json';
String bodyMultipartFormData = '--' + boundaryString + '\n' + fileHeader + '\n\n' + body  + '\n' + '--' + boundaryString + '--';
request.setBody(bodyMultipartFormData);
request.setHeader('Content-Type','multipart/form-data; boundary='+boundaryString);
request.setHeader('x-ms-blob-type','BlockBlob');
request.setHeader('x-ms-version','2021-06-08');
// Make the request
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](/tour). Including a [Minimal, Complete and Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful. Your code segment is sufficiently minimal but not complete nor reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually figured it out. As I was sending the request to Azure DataStore, most likely they are interpreting it in a windows-based machine. Whenever I added LF (`\n`), I wasn't accounting for the fact that they instead use CRLF which translates to an extra `\r` char, resulting in `\r\n` whenever they interpret a new line.

I guess, moral of the story, be mindful of the machine that you are going to make requests to.